# Is there a proof of existence of ADAM CAD?

Tags: cad

[This article](https://partsolutions.com/60-years-of-cad-infographic-the-history-of-cad-since-1957/) has [a timeline](https://partsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/2021-History-of-CAD-Infographic_2000.png) of CADs. I can find [the Digigraphics CAD manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/cdc/graphics/17303600D_274_Interactive_Graphics_System_Reference_Oct71.pdf) (1967) or [the CATIA advertising flyer](https://isicad.ru/uploads/img/29023_.JPG) (1977). But I can't find any documents about ADAM (Automated Drafting and Machining) CAD (1969). Of course, there are a lot of indirect references on the Internet about what a wonderful CAD it was. But is there any document - a magazine article from early 1970s, a commercial prospect, a photo of it's interface, a guide or a manual about this CAD or something else?

[This article](https://www.americanmachinist.com/cad-and-cam/article/21892098/the-cad-cam-hall-of-fame) tells that "*Today, an estimated 90% of commercial drafting software can trace its roots back to Dr. Hanratty's original program, called **ADAM***".

But is there any proofs of existence of ADAM CAD?

Comment: What does anyone consider proof? Is the mention of it not enough? Must you have a machine from a bygone era still operating and running a program for it to exist? What then is the proof that your ancestors existed?

Comment: @Abel In my question there is nothing about a still operating machine. I say about primary data: any technical document wrote special for ADAM.

Comment: You will probably have to look for a close relative.  ADaM may have been too early. https://archive.org/details/TNM_Imlac_Series_II_Applications_Interactive_Graphics_Terminal

Comment: It was software meant to be liscensed by other companies.  It evolved into other products.  Doubtful you will see a 1972 magazine ad [Patrick Hanratty and Manufacturing & Consulting Services](https://www.shapr3d.com/history-of-cad/patrick-hanratty-and-manufacturing-consulting-services)

Comment: Also it became a part of a lawsuit so may not of been openly marketed [The Engineering Design Revolution CAD History](https://images.designworldonline.com.s3.amazonaws.com/CADhistory/85739614-The-Engineering-Design-Revolution-CAD-History.pdf#page=429)